# Junit : how could I use assertion to check String >0

Tags: junit4

I have a String and I would like to check that this string is > 0
using assert

trying : 
using assertFalse I can't set  2 strings : my value and "0" .

Is there another way to say : assertThat "myString"> "0" ?

my purpose :

```
myTable.getValue =>this return a string : "20"
I would like to check that this string is > or different from "0"
```

thanks

Comment: You want to check if the string is > 0, or that the *length* of the string is > 0?  Can you add what your tests currently look like?

Comment: I did update the question, yes I want to check if the string is >0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really want to do the comparison as a number, for safety.  So you want something like

```
assertTrue(Integer.parseInt(myTable.getValue()) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, with `assertThat` style you may want to use:

```
assertThat(myTable.length()).isGreaterThan(0);
```

you will need to import `org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat` static methods. I'd prefer this method as enhance test readability.